# How to fix a -Wsubobject-linkage warning?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting a gcc warning for code which compiles fine and warning free in clang and VC++, so I assume it's something gcc specific. This is the code:

```
namespace myns {
  using TokenList = std::vector<size_t>;
  using RuleList = std::vector<size_t>;
  using RulePathPair = std::pair<size_t, TokenList>;
  using CandidatesCollection = struct { std::map<size_t, TokenList> tokens; std::set<RulePathPair> rules; };

  class A {
  private:
    CandidatesCollection _candidates;
  };
} // namespace myns
```

and the warning is:

> warning: 'myns::A' has a field 'myns::A::_candidates' whose type has no linkage [-Wsubobject-linkage]

What does this mean and how to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but why are you using `using` to define a type-alias for a structure? Structure-names are type-names themselves. Not saying that it's wrong, just that it's odd. :)

Comment: Right, I was thinking the same, but I wanted to keep the pattern there. I have a number of other such definitions and like this representation.

Comment: It reminded me of the old C typedef struct pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the compiler might be wrong here: the type referred to by `CandidatesCollection` should in fact have external linkage.

> **[basic.link]/4** ...A name having namespace scope that has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of
>
> ...
>
> *(4.3)* — a named class (Clause 9), or an unnamed class defined in a `typedef` declaration in which the class has the `typedef` name for linkage purposes (7.1.3); ...
>
> ---
>
> **[dcl.typedef]/9** If the `typedef` declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first *typedef-name* declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only (3.5). [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>  typedef struct { } *ps, S; // S is the class name for linkage purposes
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Thus, if `CandidatesCollection` were defined as

```
typedef struct { ... } CandidatesCollection;
```

these two passages make it clear that the class named by `CandidatesCollection` would happily have external linkage.

Then there's

> **[dcl.typedef]/2** A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The identifier following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the identifier appertains to that *typedef-name*. It has **the same semantics** as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.

Emphasis mine. This suggests that the name introduced by `using` should give the unnamed class "the name for linkage purposes" just as well as the equivalent `typedef` declaration, thereby ensuring that the class has external linkage.

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought. Didn't come to my mind clang could be on the wrong side here. Thanks for clarification. So, the only solution is not to use `using` it seems.